# No substitution in Sum when plotting

Tags: python, indexing, sympy

I would like to plot `r = Sum(1/factorial(i), (i,0,n))` for a range of `n` values. I'm able to get individual values using `subs()` and `N()`, e.g:

```
for k in [0,3,10]: print(N(r.subs(n,k)))
```

> 1.00000000000000
> 2.66666666666667
> 2.71828180114638

But I can't plot these values:

```
plot(N(r), (n,0,10))
```

The line of code above just plots the limit of the series for any value of `n`, as if `n` was ignored by the function:

[image]

I assume `plot` substitutes `n` according to the range passed to it, but I'm obviously wrong. How can I force sympy to substitute?

---

Full code:

```
from sympy import init_printing, plot, symbols
from sympy import Sum, factorial, N

init_printing()
i, n = symbols('i n', integer=True)
r = Sum(1/factorial(i), (i,0,n))
for k in [0,3,10]: print(N(r.subs(n,k)))
plot(N(r), (n,0,10))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, `sympy.plotting.plot` is rarely able to deal with summations.

We can work around it with by manually evaluating the summation and using the `marker` keyword argument:

```py
nvals = list(range(11))
plot(
    0, (n, 0, 10), # need some symbolic expression, otherwise plot creates a 3D figure :|
    markers=[{"args": [nvals, [float(r.subs(n, t).n()) for t in nvals]]}])
```

[image]

If you are looking for a better plotting module, I suggest [SymPy Plotting Backends](https://github.com/Davide-sd/sympy-plot-backends) which should be able to deal with summations:

```py
from spb import *
plot(r, (n, 0, 10),
    adaptive=False, # ask for uniformly spaced points (along n)
    only_integers=True, # ask the uniformly spaced points to be integers
    is_point=True # draw points instead of a continuous line
)
```

[image]

Comment: I tried different solutions in the meantime and [.doit()](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/core.html#sympy.core.basic.Basic.doit) seemingly works (`plot(r.doit(), (n,0,10))`). The documentation says: "*Evaluate objects that are not evaluated by default like limits, integrals, sums and products*". While this works in my case, I don't know if it's the general solution.

Comment: That works too in this simple case. However, note that you are going to plot the resulting expression over a real range (n will be real), whereas the index of a summation is an integer. Hence, keep in mind what information you want to convey with the plots :)